# How do I send a header response on a web service spring?

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc

I want get on the header response a string and I want to use it as a token in order to validate a login on my application.

This is my code:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("token","124");
```

When I consume the web service there is no field token on the header response.

Comment: What's the controller method code?